# "Disconnected or Canceled" Error when calling apex method from lightning component action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error

When calling an apex method from lightning component, especifically with one record we are getting "Disconnected or Canceled" error.

The actions is failing before leaving component and never gets to server side logic.

Executing the action from other records is working perfectly.

[image: Disconnected or Canceled error]

Comment: Can you show the calling code and perhaps the data of the specific record that is failing?

Comment: Hi @ElkCor, did you find a way to resolve this issue?